# How to understand the output of my function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was browsing around the internet and came upon this JavaScript function

```
   function foo(){
        function bar() {
            return 3;
        }
        return bar();
        function bar() {
            return 8;
        }
    }
    console.log(foo());
    =>8
```

It's really confusing why this function is returning 8 when it is called. I would assume that this code would run down the contents of the function and stop at `return bar();`and return 3. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is because function declarations get hoisted to the top of the block.

Comment: functions get hoisted - doesn't matter if it was declared after the statement, it can still be ran. The last `bar()` overwrites the first.

Comment: Just curious, is this a question of purely academic value? Why would someone write code like that? Seriously, is there a good reason?

Comment: @LogicArtist -- Was probably used in an example to demonstrate hoisting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of variable hoisting. `function` definitions go before anything else. It really looks like this

```
function foo(){
    var bar;
    bar = function() {
        return 3;
    }
    bar = function() {
        return 8;
    }
    return bar();
}
```

> "Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top." **[var<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)**

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that using `var bar = function () { … }`  in the original code would actually make a difference here.